# How does if else work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, if-statement

How do i start on an if else statement to restrict?

Fields in database :

```
No_of_vacancy (shows the number of positions available in the company)
Assigned (shows the number of student assigned to company)
```

EG

```
ABC Co 
No of vancacy = 2
Assigned student = 2
```

I have done the necessary statement

```
UPDATE job_details,
    student_details 
SET 
    assigned = assigned + 1
WHERE
    student_details.jobscope1 = job_details.jobscope
        AND student_details.jobscope1 = 'IT';
```

The above statement works fine. meaning each time query runs. 1 student will be added under assigned field in database. I want the query to stop after assigned field matches the no of vacancy field to avoid duplication.

My logic is that i have to use if else statement to restrict the amount of assigned students from going over the no of vacancy available which is 2.

how do i start?

Answer (score 3):

And if you simply add, to the `where`, `and (assigned + 1) < job_details.No_of_vacancy` ?

Comment: if ($assigned < job_details.no_of_vacancy)
{ echo "Position Filled" }

is this correct?

Comment: No. It is not correct for mySQL, however, it is almost correct for php but `job_details.no_of_vacancy` would actually be replaced by a string `job_detailsno_of_vacancy` because PHP replace unknown constant by their name (and issue a warning). 
You should edit your question and add the PHP code as well.

Comment: $a = assigned;
if($a + 1 < job_detailsno_of_vacancy)
{

   echo "Student Assigned";
}
   else ($a + 1 == job_detailsno_of_vacancy)
{ 
   echo "All position filled";